# how to encode character '\xa0' in 'ascii' codec

Tags: python, dataframe, ascii, rest

I am trying to fetch data using Here's Rest API using python but I am receiving the following error,

```
   1132 
   1133         # Non-ASCII characters should have been eliminated earlier
-> 1134         self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
   1135 
   1136         if self._http_vsn == 11:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 86: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My python code is -

```
 df = pd.read_csv(r"data.csv", encoding='utf8', sep=",", 
                 engine="python")

def GoogPlac(auth_key,lat,lon):
    location = str(lat) + ',' + str(lon)
    MyUrl = ('https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/browse'
            '?apiKey=%s'
            '&in=%s'
            ';r=2000'
            '&cat=restaurant&pretty') % (auth_key,location)
    #grabbing the JSON result
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(MyUrl)
    jsonRaw = response.read()
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonRaw)
    return jsonData

# Function call
df['response'] = df.apply(lambda x: GoogPlac(auth_key,x['latitude'],x['longitude']), axis=1)
```

I want to avoid the error and continue my API fetch

Comment: you have to pass `ignore`. Ex - `request.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

Comment: Exactly which step was supposed to eliminate the non-ascii characters?

Comment: I'm not sure about where in the code I should add the encode statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you want to avoid the error, but how you avoid it matters.

Your title says you want to encode something to ASCII, but the thing you want to encode is not encodable in ASCII. There is no A0 character in 7-bit ASCII. You've asked the impossible.

You can decide among a few different things:

- Encode with a lossy encode() parameter that says to throw away everything that doesn't fit in ASCII. This is dangerous and probably not very smart. If you can't trust your data, then why are you using your data?
- Use a different encoding for output. You seem to know what encoding your text was, because you could fetch it and render it to Unicode. (OR, you are using ancient Python 2, and the default system encoding understands that page's encoding, and there's a silent `.decode(DEFAULT_ENCODING)` right before your `.encode("ascii")` . This is by far the best scheme. Just don't use ASCII. UTF-8 is the present and future!
- Specifically snip out A0 with `.replace()` before your `.encode()`. Also pretty bad.
- Get your page author to agree it should be ASCII and get himher to fix it. This is best of all.

Comment: Thank you very much :)