# 'ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, ascii, cross-validation

I use python3.8 in Windows, Here is my code

```
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from matplotlib import pyplot

# get a list of models to evaluate
def get_models():
    models = dict()
    for i in range(2, 29):
        rfe = RFE(estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(), n_features_to_select=i)
        model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        models[str(i)] = Pipeline(steps=[('s',rfe),('m',model)])
    return models

# evaluate a give model using cross-validation
def evaluate_model(model, x, y):
    cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=7)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, x, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs= -1, error_score='raise')
    return scores

# get the models to evaluate
models = get_models()
# evaluate the models and store results
results, names = list(), list()
for name, model in models.items():
    scores = evaluate_model(model, x, y)
    results.append(scores)
    names.append(name)
    print('>%s %.3f (%.3f)' % (name, mean(scores), std(scores)))
# plot model performance for comparison
pyplot.boxplot(results, labels=names, showmeans=True)
pyplot.show()
```

The problem is:

```
D:\software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in _send(self, cmd, name, rtype)
    202 
    203     def _send(self, cmd, name, rtype):
--> 204         msg = '{0}:{1}:{2}\n'.format(cmd, name, rtype).encode('ascii')
    205         if len(name) > 512:
    206             # posix guarantees that writes to a pipe of less than PIPE_BUF
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried many solutions such as add:

```
import sys 
import imp
imp.reload(sys)
```

And I think there is no Chinese character in my dataset.

Thing is, if I remove the `n_jobs=-1` parameter in `scores = cross_val_score` part, the code works but it runs really slow as there would be only one core working. Any solution for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to encode character '\xa0' in 'ascii' codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391602/how-to-encode-character-xa0-in-ascii-codec)

Comment: @Joe I'm afraid not, but now I figure out the reason, because the user name for my computer is in Chinese character, so I have change the user name and now the code works. But still many thanks for your help!